# Main.axml doesn't load

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I just started using Xamarin and after reading the basic stuff I wanted to give it a try and develop a basic app. When I start a new project or load one. My Main.axml is there (I can see the layout), but when I go to Source and come back to the Designer a couple of times, the Designer load bar stays in loading and nothing happens; even without changing anything in the code.

I already tried:
- Restarting my PC.
- Executing Visual Studio as admin.
- Allowing Visual Studio in the firewall.

I have Visual Studio 15 Community Update 3 and Xamarin Plugin up to date.